# How to trisect a wide screen?

Tags: unity, tmux

What is the handiest way for the user to trisect `Tmux` terminal screen horizontally into left-middle-right or vertically top-middle-bottom tiles, preferably by pressing the shortcut keys just once?

The same question goes for `Unity` to split the desktop space.

In either case I can put the most active job on the middle tile in the center of a wide screen thus watch it more straightly.

(Something like using `Tmux` to split into halves twice or dragging the window on `Unity` is not my intention.)

Comment: They are two slightly different cases. `Tmux` has only one window so I need a shortcut to trisect it at first. But each `desktop app` running on `Unity` has its own window so I need another shortcut to move the `App window` to the middle section.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not too sure what you asking as it seems kinda unnecessary and self explanatory. As far as I know all you can do in ubuntu or any linux, is split the screen. Even then you can only split the windows...this can be done by clicking and dragging a window, to the far right or left of the screen. What this will do is maximize the window on half of the screen. You can also do the same by running [ctrl] + [super], then using the up left and right arrow keys...Now i'm not sure why you would want to 
trisect your screen, as it would make the windows harder to read or see...But if you want you can adjust the size of the windows, and throw one in the middle...Now keep in mind you do have multiple workspaces in Linux, and if you dont you'll have to enable them. to do this simply go into your system settings, and inside of the behavior settings for the appearance you want to click enable work spaces. and that will give you some more space to work arround with. I hope I answer your noob like question...I only wish I was high enough reputation to down vote this waste of time question.